# WCF - three classes created

Tags: .net, wcf, asmx

When you add a new Service reference it appears that three new classes are created.  Say I created a service reference called TestService, then I see the following classes:

```
TestServiceSoap
TestServiceSoapClient
TestServiceSoapChannel
```

All my experience with web services involves the ASMX variety.  However, I now need to consume a WCF web service and hence the reason for the question.  I assume that they are for the ABC of WCF web services i.e. Address, Binding, Channel but I have not found anything to support this assumption.

I have spent half an hour Googling this and was surprised not to find an answer.  I am sure there will be a similar question on here, but I cannot find it.

Update 14/09/13 09:53
Please see the screen shot below:

[image]

Notice that there is a Service Reference in solution explorer called HelloWorldServiceReference.  I have an option to create an instance of one of the three classes above.

Comment: Did you add the reference via Add Service Reference?  It sounds like you're looking at the reference.cs/reference.vb file, which is auto-generated.  Not sure about the first two classes, but the last one is the client you use to communicate with the service.  Can you post more of the code?

Comment: The three files do not correspond with the ABC of the endpoint. The ABC is defined in the app config which was generated alongside your classes.

Comment: @Tim, I have added more information.  Does this help to answer the question?

Comment: @w0051977 - based on your screen shot, `TestWebServiceSoap` is an interface, not a class, and it is your service contract.  `TestWebServiceSoapChannel` is also an interface.  `TestWebServiceSoapClient` is a class and that is your proxy for communicating with the service.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot definitely helps.  It looks like what you have is two interfaces and one class, not three classes.  Without seeing your service code or reference.cs, here's an educated guess as to what they are:

`TestWebServiceSoap` is most likely the contract (interface) for your service.

`TestWebServiceSoapChannel` is an interface as well, that implements both your service contract (interface) and `IClientChannel` interface.  `IClientChannel` "Defines the behavior of outbound request and request/reply channels used by client applications."

`TestWebServiceSoapClient` is a class, and this is the proxy your application would use to communicate with the service.  It derives from `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<T>`, where `T` is your service contract.

I'm not sure why the first two interfaces are not named like interfaces (i.e., `ITestWebServiceSoap` and `ITestWebServiceSoapChannel`).

But the most important class is the `TestWebServiceSoapClient` class, which as I said is your proxy.

Comment: Thanks.  +1.  Is there any socumentation to support this? I cannot find any.